# Как убрать ссылку в telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пишу бота на телеботе, он отправляет текст с гипперссылкой, но эта ссылка показывается в дополнительном окне снизу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это убрать?

Comment: Если вы используете библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI решение описано  [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535901/pytelegrambotapi-disable-link-preview)

Answer (score 2):

Нужно добавить disable_web_page_preview. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage
Вот пример кода:

```
tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
tb.send_message(123456, "Hi <link>", disable_web_page_preview=True)
```